# Custom Magento Homepage - Fix Issue

Tags: magento, plugins, indexing, magento-1.4

So the previous web developer has customized our Magento v1.4.1 site to use a page called main.php... It bypasses everything else that is set by Magento as far as Magento goes.

I have no way contact the previous developer to ask where this is setup...

We have just installed a new plugin and it has taken over as the homepage.

In Magento Admin > System > Configuration > Web the homepage is set to URL Key "home" ... When I go to that specific page index.php/home, the custom main.php page shows up. Why would a plugin have found it's way to be our homepage?

Thanks! Felt like my previous question didn't give enough details.

Comment: Have you checked under CMS > Manage Content  and look for the page named "home"? What is in that page?

Comment: It is just a blank page. Somewhere (not in the CMS) this page ("home") is being told to display the content from main.php ... http://myurl.com/index.php/home and http://myurl.com/home show the content of main.php where http://myurl.com show this random template of the new plugin. I have temporarly bypassed the issue in htaccess --- [## default index file   DirectoryIndex main.php index.php] ---

Answer (score 0):

"home" is not the normal value, here is what that section should look like:

[image: default web configuration]

Comment: This is exactly how mine is setup. The page titled "Home page" (with the URL Key "home") is set as the "CMS Home Page." It's the uStoreLocator plugin that has found its way to the homepage.